# Counting/Finding the boundary points in a 2-D point cloud

Tags: c

There are finite number of points on a 2-D plane each on integer coordinates (x,y) such that 0<=x,y<100.
Now what could be done to find out all the boundary points of this set? (Algorithm)
Visualisation of boundary points:
Imagine a rubber band in your hand.
Imagine pins sticked at all the points on the plane.
Now if you release the rubber band such that all the points/pins are inside it, after releasing it will contract.
After contraction, the points that deviate the rubber band(make perfect corners) will be the boundary points.
Image Visualisation: [Image](http://in.mathworks.com/help/examples/matlab/BoundaryOf2DPointCloudExample_03.png)  (Posting link to image coz i do not have enough reputation points)
Consider the yellow line. The image is not perfect visualisation. There's a point at ~(0.8,1) which should lie inside the boundary.

Comment: Is there a programming question?

Comment: yes. Ignoring time limit, what algorithm could be used to solve it?

Comment: This is called [computing the convex hull.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms)

Comment: i never knew its called by a name. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) library or the [cgal](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PartConvexHullAlgorithms) library implement convex hull algorithms. Additional [references](http://www.qhull.org/html/index.htm#description) can be found on their website.